# Is there a way to "eat" events in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, events

Is there a way to "eat" other listeners of an event?

```
x.on("test", function(x){
    if(x==4) {
        console.log("Event1");
    }
});
x.on("test", function(x){
    if(x==5) {
        console.log("Event2");
    }
});
x.on("test", function(x){
    console.log("Event3");
});
x.emit("test", 4);
x.emit("test", 5);
x.emit("test", -1);
```

Is there a way to make event 1 "eat" (not allow it to happen) the other events if x is 4?

Without adding if(x!=4&&x!=5) to event 3 (if there are many listeners it may get annoying quickly).

Bonus: Can I have a "fallback" event to catch events that don't have any listener.

Comment: for your solution why not add a flag like `eventTest.eaten = true;` and check it :) ; I not sure if anybody guarantee that events will be fired in same queue they was set.

Comment: you can also use object as event data like '{value: 111, eaten: false}` and set eaten to true when fire event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `EventEmitter` built into node does not support "eating" of other event handlers or having a "catch-all" event handler. If you need that kind of functionality you will have to use one of the other `EventEmitter` implementations on npm.

Comment: I found eventif usefull for conditionals listeners. Still I dont find a modul for catch-all.

Answer (score 0):

you can simply try this

```
    x.on("test", function(x){

        switch(x){
            case 4:         
                console.log("Event1");
                break;
            case 5:
                console.log("Event2");
                break;
            default:
                console.log("Event3");

        }

    });
    x.emit("test", 4);
    x.emit("test", 5);
    x.emit("test", -1);
```

Comment: My idea is to avoid doing that. And the "catch-all" is for ALL THE EVENTS, not just "test".